# Given two subspaces, $$ and $$, of the same dimension within $\mathbb{R}^6$, find the possible values of $\operatorname{dim}( ∩ )$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two subspaces, $$ and $$, of the same dimension within $\mathbb{R}^6$, I do not understand how to find the possible values of $\operatorname{dim}( ∩ )$.

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682387/possible-dimensions-of-the-intersection-of-two-subspaces), I understand the dimension of subspaces cannot be bigger than the one containing them.

Say $\operatorname{dim}() = \operatorname{dim}() = 5$. Then how would I use the following fact? Where does the inequality come from?

$\operatorname{dim}( + ) = \operatorname{dim}() + \operatorname{dim}() − \operatorname{dim}( ∩ )$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\dim(U\cap V)$, $p=\dim U=\dim V,$ and $n=\dim E$ (the ambient space). Then,
$$2p-d=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)=\dim(U+V)\le n,$$
i.e.
$$d\ge2p-n.$$
This is the only constraint on $d$, apart of course from being $\ge0$ and $\le p.$ Hence the possible values for $d$ are:
$$m,m+1,m+2,\dots,p,\quad\text{where}\quad m=\max(0,2p-n).$$
In your example: $n=6,$ $p=5,$ and $m=2p-n=4.$

Comment: What property of subspaces tells you n = 6 (i.e., dim E)? Is it the fact that U and V are contained in R6? Are "vector space" and "ambient space" interchangeable?

Comment: @HikikiMe Yes and yes. The ambient space $E$ is the given vector space of which $U$ and $V$ are subspaces. In the example $E=\mathbb R^6.$

Answer (score 1):

If $\hbox{dim}U=\hbox{dim}V=5$, then $\hbox{dim}(U+V)$ is either $5$ or $6$, hence by the formula you quoted,  $\hbox{dim}(U\cap V)$ is either $4$ or $5$.
In general, if $\hbox{dim}V=\hbox{dim}U=x$, then $\hbox{dim}(U+V)$ is one of the numbers $x,x+1,\dots,\min\{2x,6\}$, and so $\hbox{dim}(U\cap V)$ can be any number between $2x-\min\{2x,6\}$ and $x$.